# Debugging why the HTML Cache isn't working

Tags: html

I was wondering if anybody could direct me to any tools for debugging the cache.manifest file in offline HTML5 access. I recently downloaded a program called Manifesto which allows me to look up the cache manifest on loading a page. Everything seems to working fine however it keeps on saying that the status is "uncached". Obviously, it seems like although it is checking to make sure the cache files are there, it isn't actually caching them upon load. Whats going on and more importantly, how do I figure out how to solve it?

Comment: Make sure you don't specify the whole path of the files. specify the relative path of those files with respect to the manifest file in the folder.

Comment: The file paths should be good. Manifesto is saying that it is finding all the files necessary. Question: Does the browser automatically cache a webpage if the manifest attribute is thrown on the html? It seems like although its looking for every file it isn't actually caching them.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. To be honest, it might have been working before but because I was having some different php scripts running in the background I had to be a little careful with pulling it up.